# How to dynamically create methods with parameter in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, metaprogramming

How can I dynamically create methods like this using ruby metaprogramming ?

```
class CommentBridge < Bridge

  def id(comment)
    comment.id
  end

  def message(comment)
    comment.message
  end

  def votes_count(comment)
    comment.votes_count
  end

end
```

I tried this but it is not working.

```
  ['id', 'message', 'votes_count'].each do |method|
    define_method "#{method}" do |parameter|
      method(parameter.method)
    end
  end
```

Comment: how is it not working? Throwing an error of some kind? Does it have to do with mixing up a string and a method? (`.each do |method|` and then later on `method(...)`)?

Comment: You can simply delegate those methods to `comment`.

Comment: ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1)) 
@SimpleLime

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `public_send` to call methods based on their name:

```
  ['id', 'message', 'votes_count'].each do |method|
    define_method "#{method}" do |parameter|
      parameter.public_send(method)
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that you need different comment every time (probably you do). So I'd recommend to simply get rid of this `comment` argument.
There are the options.

Using RubyOnRails (I see you question is tagged so) you can use [`delegate`](https://apidock.com/rails/Module/delegate) (as @SimpleLime has already commented)

```
class CommentBridge < Bridge
  attr_reader :comment
  def initialize(comment_)
    @comment = comment_)
  end
  delegate :id, :message, :votes_count, to: :comment
end
```

In case of pure Ruby 2 use [`Forwardable`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/forwardable/rdoc/Forwardable.html):

```
class CommentBridge
  extend Forwardable
  attr_reader :comment
  def initialize(comment_)
    @comment = comment_)
  end
  def_delegators :comment, :id, :message, :votes_count
end
```

If you want to provide additional methods on top of you comment object and forward all the rest methods use [`SimpleDelegator`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.1/libdoc/delegate/rdoc/SimpleDelegator.html) (assuming that this Brigde in namgin means that your class is just a wrapper):

```
class CommentDecorator < SimpleDelegator
  def hello
    'hello'
  end
end

comment = Commend.find(params[:id])
decorated_comment = CommentDecorator.new(comment)
```

---

You can also define `method missing`:

```
class CommentBridge < Bridge
  attr_reader :comment
  def initialize(comment_)
    @comment = comment_)
  end

  def method_missing(m, *args)
    if [:id, :message, :comment].include?(m)
      comment.public_send(method, *args)
    else
      super
    end
  end
end
```

Finally, you can create your own delegation-DSL on top of `define_method`, but I think this is the extra in that case.

I don't think that `method_missing` or `define_method` inside loop is neat although it works.